# Simultneous depth and video from kinect

Tags: opencv, driver, kinect, rgb

I want to get both depth and video from streams from the kinect to my opencv code. I am working in Linux. I have installed libfreenect module for depth. However, there is only one device listed in /dev/. Now, when I connect the Kinect to my pc and run

```
camorama -d /dev/video0
```

I get the depth map. Then, I access the device using videocapture in opencv and I get the rgb video. Now, if I again run the camorama command, I get the rgb video this time. I can't figure out what's happening. I basically want both the stream in my opencv code. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Run this python script:

```
import freenect
import cv2
import numpy as np
from functions import *

def nothing(x):
    pass   
kernel = np.ones((5, 5), np.uint8)     

def pretty_depth(depth):
    np.clip(depth, 0, 2**10 - 1, depth)
    depth >>= 2
    depth = depth.astype(np.uint8)
    return depth

while 1:
    orig = freenect.sync_get_video()[0]
    orig = cv2.cvtColor(orig,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    dst = pretty_depth(freenect.sync_get_depth()[0])#input from kinect
    cv2.imshow('Disparity', dst)
    cv2.imshow('RGB',orig)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('b'):
        break
```